# "NVIDIA-SMI has failed" after installing cuda 10.0

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, gpu

I'm a beginner and I'm following [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/12/09/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-0-on-ubuntu/) on how to create a deep learning environment.  `Nvidia-smi`  **was working** when I installed nvidia drivers, but after installing Cuda (which went successfully) it stopped working properly. Output:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

```
 nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

Secure boot is disabled, I have tried rebooting, and   `sudo prime-select nvidia`

Comment: During those installation steps, in the step for installing the CUDA itself from the .run file, did you unselect the NVIDIA driver install part?  I have heard of issues when installing the driver that comes with the .run file.  There is a chance that it might have removed the driver.  Also, does your BIOS have Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't unselect, I typed yes for all the questions. Should I uninstall everything and start from scratch? And yes Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: Yes, that would be recommended to remove the driver and CUDA, then start it over.  The good part is when you run the `.run` file for the installation, unselecting the NVIDIA driver allows you to use the driver that is compatible with your video card.

Comment: Thank you. Unselecting the driver install in Cuda solved the problem.

Comment: please explain how you did it. If possible by posting an Answer to your own question.